# HttpClient, how to click button on website in tests

Tags: c#, testing, integration-testing

I have page where i have button which makes ajax-request to server and load simple modal form. I have one input and one button in form.

How i can test it on C# ?
I need just navigate to link -> click -> load form. Then just input text and click button.

I dont want use selenium for it.

Comment: "*I dont want use selenium*" - that's fair enough, but at least put why you don't want to use such a tool. I mean, what if someone tenders and answer using another tool, who knows if you don't want to use that or not. Its also likely that your expectations of how this can be reliably tested are suspect. We don't know.. Please consider editing the question

Comment: Short answer - your life will be easier with Selenium / phantomjs / headless Chrome.

Comment: The moment you step into another application, like a Web browser, and stop talking directly to an API, that's the moment when you have to drive the UI somehow. With Client applications you'd use an Automation framework and for browsers, tools like Selenium are the automation frameworks that you must communicate with to drive the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx, it really only selenium. So i just need to use it.